# Where to put try-catch statements

Tags: coding-style, coding-standards

I have the following code statement that calls a separate class.

```
if (newOrEdit.Equals("New"))
{
    try
    {
        BusinessLayer.InsertOperator(operatorDetails);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error unable to insert details.");
    }

}
```

This calls a simple method that tries to insert the operator.

I have seen the same method done as follows

```
if (newOrEdit == "New")
{
    if (Business.insertNewUser(userDetails))
    {
        this.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to insert new user", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Now this method accepts a boolean back and inside the method it has the try catch inside the business class.

Which of the following is better and why?

Comment: The answer to this question depends on what your language and design goals are, but will likely end up being primarily opinion-based regardless. Also, I reworded the part of your question asking about best practices: [this is problematic and generally ends poorly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing).

Comment: This depends very much on the language. This question isn't tagged with a language, but the code appears to be Java. In python, using exceptions for flow control is standard operating procedure, EAFP (Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission).

Comment: The code looks more like C# to me (otherwise the use of == for string comparison is an error). That said, the conventions around exceptions are pretty much the same in both languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general best practice is to only use exceptions on *exceptions*. The process of creating an exception and throwing it is generally very costly, so should be avoided for things that can fail through fairly normal operation.

Validation is a good example of this. People are going to send in garbage inputs all the time. That is an error, but not *exceptional* - so don't use exceptions.

So if inserting a new user should almost always succeed (baring some exceptional circumstance, like a lightning strike killing your network) then try/catch is fine. If inserting a new user might commonly fail, then the success bool would be better.

Comment: Though those functions which are expected to regularly fail are typically called `TryOperation` to make it obvious that they don't throw on the most likely error-condition, and the result must be checked.

Comment: @Deduplicator - yes, excellent point.

Comment: See also [the .net framework design guidelines on exceptions and performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Exception handling tends to be a fairly expensive operation, so if you are writing the code that is called, and you can handle it gracefully then you should.

If you are writing the code that can have an error condition, consider whether the error you are handling is recoverable. It would be rather harsh to force an exception to be thrown for a simple data entry error.

Comment: Expensive relative to what? How expensive is a catch relative to say showing a message box to the user and waiting for the user to click ok?

Comment: Relative to explicitly handling the error at the point it occurred typically.

Comment: @JacquesB An exception goes back up the stack until it finds an enclosing catch block and calls all finalizers. After it finds a catch block it transfers control to the first line in the catch block. There is a lot of crawling up the stack and jumping required in exceptions. It isn't a binary use exceptions or use a message box. In a validation situation you would use both when using exceptions. You would wrap the validation in a try/catch and then use a message box to show it. If you know that the input has to be validated you can save some time by validating yourself instead of an exception

Answer (score 1):

There are two common mis-uses of the exception mechanism:  First, is to use it as a standard event information channel (which is not what it's designed for);  second, is to "swallow" exceptions in a way that hides problems from you.

The result of doing either of these is that the exception/error gets managed at an inappropriate point in the code.  How many times have you received an exception thrown, but it's cause is some code way up the chain?  Often! (if you've been doing this for any amount of time!)

For example:  You have a little yourPackage.util.ConvertDate class.  It does a reflection invocation on your input and gives you some derived value, but if one of your input values to a private internal method is null, it will throw an IllegalArgumentException or perhaps an InvocationTargetException.  In an ideal world, that method would be defined as "throws IllegalArgumentException" and that exception would "bubble up" to the next level.  In well designed exception trees, that exception would keep passing through "throws" declarations until it hit the very same line of code that set the unusable value!

The concept here is to have the exception bubble up to the exact spot in your code where you can effect the best recovery.

Another example:  you have a database insert routine that fails because there's a null value in your PreparedStatement parameters, for a non-nullable field in the database. It throws an SQLException.  If you "swallow" that exception and pass up a boolean false return value to show that a record wasn't inserted into the DB, (and likely you ignore the return value) then later on when you discover that your object doesn't exist, you have no way of knowing whether it was because of a null value, because there was something ELSE wrong with that value (i.e. putting a string into a BIGINT field) or that there was a syntax error in your SQL statement or even if you'd momentarily lost network connection to the database!  When you handled the exception down where you had no ability to make a relevant choice in the matter and SOLVE it, then you caused yourself a big huge debugging headache later on.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a black-and-white question that could receive an answer such as "A is *always* better" or "Avoid B at all costs", but generally:

**The preferred way is exceptions, not status results.**

(And for the sake of consistency it is best to avoid converting between the two unless you have a good reason.  Which in this case, I don't see.)

The code fragments that you posted are top-level code.  When writing top-level code, (where it may make sense to try and catch exceptions,) the use of exceptions might seem cumbersome and unnecessarily verbose when compared to the use of status results.  However, you have to consider that top-level code is not the only code that makes up a non-trivial application; this `InsertOperator()` method may represent (or may be invoked by) a several-level-deep call tree, consisting of hundreds of lines of code, where each and every method invoked must return a status result, and each and every caller must be sure to check this status result and take appropriate action if not successful. Quite often programmers forget that stuff; that's when hard-to-find bugs happen.

With exceptions, code below the top level which does not have any need to deal with an exception does not have to contain a `try-catch` block, and if it needs to deal with exceptions only for the purpose of leaving things as it found them, it can simply use `try-finally` instead of `try-catch`.  This generally results in much simpler, much more structured, much more understandable, and much more maintainable code than the kind of spaghetti code that we used to write back in the days of result codes, before exceptions had been invented.

Of course, as always, there may be good enough reasons to choose result codes instead of exceptions.  As other answers have already indicated, if something is to be happening so often as to practically not be considered an "exceptional situation", then perhaps it should not be expressed as an exception, and the performance penalty associated with throwing an exception might be prohibitive.  But in your case, failing to add a "user" or an "operator" seems a severe enough and exceptional enough situation to warrant precisely that: an exception.